# TypeError: 'Connection' object is not callable in python scripting using mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, database

```
import MySQLdb

class database():

 def __init__(self, host, user, pwd, db):

  self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, pwd, db)

  self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

# FUNCTION FOR DATABASE VIEW #
 def db(self):

#SQL command
  sql = "select * from details"
  try:
  self.cursor.execute(sql)

  results = self.cursor.fetchall()

  for row in results:
   print row[0], row [1], row[2]

  except:
   print "error"

#Closing database
 self.db.close()

db = database('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'test')

db.db()
```

with this code, im getting error as connection object is not callable.
My objective is to create single connection object and use it for various sql queries. Im new to python scripting. So if anyone help to overcome this error, it will be much useful for me to move further in my coding. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that you have defined a function called def in your database class. But then inside the `__init__` method of that same class you do this.

```
self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, pwd, db)
```

Which replaces the function you have just made with a MySQLdb connection object. Hence the error.

Lots people when they start off working with a database api wry to create a wrapper for that API, however that only just adds complexity to the code. Usually database APIs are well designed. Please consider using it directly without a wrapper.

Comment: got it :) tqsm.. actually function i created is db. Anyway i understand ur answer from my colleague ;)